# Check and display errors in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, csv

I have this codes:

```
    private string ErrorMessage(string input)
    {
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                return input;
            BtnImport1.Visible = false; 
        }
        return "No value entered!";

    }

    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strFileNameOnServer = fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
        string fileExt =
        System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileUpload.FileName);

        if (fileUpload.PostedFile != null && fileExt == ".csv")
        {
            try
            {
                fileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"));
                Label1.Text = "File name: " +
                       fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName + "<br>" +
                       fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength + " kb<br>" +
                       "Content type: " +
                       fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Error saving <b>" + strFileNameOnServer + "</b><br>.  " + ex.Message;
            }
            BtnImport1.Visible = true;
            Cancel.Visible = true;
            fileUpload.Visible = false;
            btnUpload.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {

            Label1.Text = "Error - a file name must be specified/only csv files are allowed";
            return;

        }

        var data = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"))
          .Select(line => line.Split(','))
          .Select(columns => new { GuestID = ErrorMessage(columns[0]), IC_No = ErrorMessage(columns[1]), Grouping = ErrorMessage(columns[2]), Remarks = ErrorMessage(columns[3]), GuestName = ErrorMessage(columns[4]), Class_Group = ErrorMessage(columns[5]), Staff = ErrorMessage(columns[6]), Attendance_Parents_Only = ErrorMessage(columns[7]), Registration = ErrorMessage(columns[8]) });

        myGridView.DataSource = data; 
        myGridView.DataBind();

    }
```

Currently, if there are empty fields in the gridview, it will display "No value entered", but, this is only for column[1] to column [7]. If I were to upload the csv file with column[8] and column[0] containing no value, the debugger would stop as there is an error. How do I avoid this? Please help!

Comment: What does the ErrorMessage method do? What are its parameters and what does it return?

Comment: What is the error the debugger shows you?

Comment: @Icarus - The ErrorMessage method is shown at the start of OP's code.

Comment: @Tim it shows "index was outside the bounds of the array"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var data = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"))
              .Select(line => line.Split(','))
              .Select(columns => new { GuestID = ErrorMessage(columns[0]), IC_No = ErrorMessage(columns[1]), Grouping = ErrorMessage(columns[2]), Remarks = ErrorMessage(columns[3]), GuestName = ErrorMessage(columns[4]), Class_Group = ErrorMessage(columns[5]), Staff = ErrorMessage(columns[6]), Attendance_Parents_Only = ErrorMessage(columns[7]), Registration = ErrorMessage(columns[8]) });
```

To this:

```
var data = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"))
          .Select(line => line.Split(','))
          .Select(columns => new { GuestID = ErrorMessage(columns.Length<=8?"":columns[0]), IC_No = ErrorMessage(columns[1]), Grouping = ErrorMessage(columns[2]), Remarks = ErrorMessage(columns[3]), GuestName = ErrorMessage(columns[4]), Class_Group = ErrorMessage(columns[5]), Staff = ErrorMessage(columns[6]), Attendance_Parents_Only = ErrorMessage(columns[7]), Registration = ErrorMessage(columns.Length<=8?"":columns[8]) });
```

**UPDATE:** Expanding my answer to answer second question.

Change your ErroMessage method to this:

```
private string ErrorMessage(string input, string dataTypeExpected="string")   
{

        switch (dataTypeExpected)
        {
            case "string": if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                            return input;
                            break;
            case "int": 
                  int result=-1;
                  if (int.TryParse(input, out result))
                       return result.ToString();
                  else return "Error: value must be an integer";

         }                

         return "No value entered!";
 }
```

And also change the var data... part to this (pay attention how I pass columns[7] & columns[8] to the ErrorMessage method):

```
var data = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"))
              .Select(line => line.Split(','))
              .Select(columns => new { GuestID = ErrorMessage(columns.Length<=8?"":columns[0]), IC_No = ErrorMessage(columns[1]), Grouping = ErrorMessage(columns[2]), Remarks = ErrorMessage(columns[3]), GuestName = ErrorMessage(columns[4]), Class_Group = ErrorMessage(columns[5]), Staff = ErrorMessage(columns[6]), Attendance_Parents_Only = ErrorMessage(columns[7],"int"), Registration = ErrorMessage(columns.Length<=8?"":columns[8],"int") });
```

Explanation: I rewrote the ErrorMessage function to receive an extra optional parameter (defaulted to "string") called dataTypeExpected. You can use that parameter to indicate the data type that the input parameter should be in. If the data passed in is an empty string or a string that does not contain digits and you specify the dataTypeExpected parameter to be "int" (as I did above), the error message will say "Error: value must be an integer";

Notice that I removed the line  `BtnImport1.Visible = false;`  from the ErrorMessage method because you are executing that line once for every time the ErrorMessage is called when you only need to execute it once. So, move that line to some place else.

Comment: @lcarus, btw, I wanna ask, can I  check if the last 2 columns are integer, and display an error if the 2 columns contain string, can I do that? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Check my answer again, @Mark20

Comment: @lcarus, I have tried the codes, but it only works if there is a string entered, if the field is empty, the debugger would stop and still display the error "index was outside the bounds of the array".